# How to use ECR Image in Jenkins ECS plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-ecs

I have a Jenkins server with **Amazon EC2 Container Service Plugin** installed. I am able to run a slave in ECS using example images like **jenkins/jnlp-slave**, but i want to use my own custom image that is present in AWS ECR repository as slave.

I have given the Image name as {ID}.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/python-slave:latest in ECS template in Configure system section,
[image]

But it is not able to bring up the slave. I went to the ECS cluster to see the cause of error, I can see in the task details that for ECR images it is trying to use the following command to bring up the containers,

```
-url http://xyz:8084/ b0a06a93aa32251b22ae3a1a198e2d8a2057f2808b7947ed612b9e1eebb109c5 'ecs java slave-4b15n'
```

It is failing with the error as,

```
Status reason   CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-url\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
Command ["-url","http://xyz:8084/","b0a06a93aa32251b22ae3a1a198e2d8a2057f2808b7947ed612b9e1eebb109c5","ecs java slave-4b15n"]
Privileged  false
```

But if i use example image like **jenkins/jnlp-slave**, it is using the following command and running fine

```
jenkins-agent -url http://xyz:8084/ bf8b42ab34d2691732026d8f454027c46d4ddaf9e9a7abc5af9c1ce417facf7a 'ecs java slave-x6p3z'
```

I have tried to find out the exact reason for this behaviour but no luck. Is there anyway we can use ECR image as jenkins Slave using ECS plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well. You MUST use the jnlp-slave image, or the extended image with build tools or cloudbees slave image ( if you are using cloudbees ).

You then extend the docker image by adding the libraries you want to it. You can add images to it with 'apt-get'

An example of extended the slave image with python

```
FROM jenkins/jnlp-slave:latest
RUN apt-get install -y -f python3 python3-pip
```

treat it like a generic debian image. you can install whatever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

for pulling the ECR image we should authenticate the docker client with the registry, then only you should be able to pull the image

eg. 
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)

Comment: The ECS instance is able to pull the image, but not able to run it as a container due to command starting from -url not jenkins-agent as describe in question

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I pushed a custom image to the docker hub and gave the path of it in the ECS Container Service Plugin as "username/repo". Remember that there would be a version of the image with a tag "latest". I'm still figuring out how to do the same with a custom image on ECR. I Will update here once I resolve it.